# Java HTTPS Proxy/Redirect Server

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, https, proxy-server

I am trying to have a server (written in java) redirect to a HTTPS url (the url will never change) when accessed. If I compile the code with

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=mySrvKeystore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password ProxyServer
```

and enter in the address, port, and localport as

```
https://google.com 443 5000
```

And try accessing

```
localhost:5000
```

on my machine, then I get the error

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: https://google.com
```

After debugging, I am pretty sure it breaks in this code block when I try to create the SSLSocket (secureServer).

```
    SSLSocket secureServer;
    try { 
        SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        secureServer = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(host, port);
        from_server = secureServer.getInputStream();
        to_server = secureServer.getOutputStream();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument you pass as the host to `factory.createSocket(host,port)` must not have the protocol prepended to it.  It should simply be `google.com`.

The reason is that Java is going to take that `host` parameter and pass it as input to a DNS lookup.  If you were to type `host https://google.com` on the command line, you'd get a similar failure.

Comment: Thanks! that let it connect the socket and streams but for some reason its not displaying the website and starting a download of an empty file...time for more debugging.

Comment: @sko Glad to hear it!  If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it...doing so helps motivate people to keep answering questions. :)

Comment: more : don't use IP address. see java bug : https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8133196

Answer (score 0):

In [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8133196), it says this was a bug and resolved after some releases

In jdk 6 server, we get the same exception but in our jdk 8 server, no exception